# Reading multiple csv files, concatenate list of file names them into a singe DataFrame

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple csv files in directory and I would loop thru to csv files find a list of files names and read each one in and concatenate them into a single data frame. In the case of a single, just read the dataset in.

Here example of csv files I have in my Directory:

- 2013_nba.csv
- 2014_nba.csv
- 2015_nba.csv
- 2013_basketball.csv
- 2014_basketball.csv
- 2015_soccer.csv

This is what I have so far. But this basically reads all csv files and concatenate them into a single DF. I need help one how to loop thru to find find list of strings(csv)

```
path = 'C:\\Users\csvfiles\\'
csvFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

list_ = []

for files in csvFiles:
     df = pd.read_csv(files, index_col=None, header=0)
     list_.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(list_, ignore_index=True)
```

I am newby in python, I try to do "for "nba" in files" to pull all csv files names have "nba" in and then make one DF, but wasn't successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

a bit improved version of `get_merged_csv()` function which can pass through parameters to `pd.read_csv()`:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

def get_merged_csv(flist, **kwargs):
    return pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, **kwargs) for f in flist], ignore_index=True)

path = 'C:/Users/csvfiles'
fmask = os.path.join(path, '*nba*.csv')

df = get_merged_csv(glob.glob(fmask), index_col=None, usecols=['rank', 'name'])

print(df.head())
```

**OLD version**:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

path = 'C:/Users/csvfiles'
#fmask = '*.csv'

def get_merged_csv(path, fmask):
    return pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, index_col=None, header=0)
                      for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, fmask))]
           )

df_list = [get_merged_csv(path, fmask)
           for fmask in ['*nba.csv', '*basketball.csv', '*soccer.csv']]
```

`df_list` will have three DFs: `df_list[0]` - NBA, `df_list[1]` - basketball, `df_list[1]` - soccer

alternatively you can put them into a dictionary:

```
df_dict = {}
df_dict['nba'] = get_merged_csv(path, '*nba.csv')
df_dict['basketball'] = get_merged_csv(path, '*basketball.csv')
df_dict['soccer'] = get_merged_csv(path, '*soccer.csv')
```

Some explanations:

`get_merged_csv(path, fmask)` function reads CSV files in the `list comprehension` loop, this list of DFs will be passed to the `pd.concat()`  function which will return single concatenated DF

Comment: I am looking to make 3 different df, one for all files contains "nba", other one for "basketball" and last one "soccer". What you done is making only for 'nba' csv files

Comment: this work perfectly Thank you so much. Do you mind explaining how this works? also I realized reading csv files as ends with "*nba.csv" or "*basketball.csv" Just for in the future what if I had files names "2014_nba_usa.csv" and "2014_basket_usa.csv"  how would I do something like this, since both files end with "usa.csv". Best way is do "*nba_usa.csv" or is there way to just take "nba" from middle of the file name

Comment: If what I asked doesnt makes sense thats fine :) I just want to learn, for future. Many thanks!

Comment: @MahmutKilic, sure, you can simply specify another file mask: '`*basket*.csv`, `*nba*.csv`, etc.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much again!!

Comment: Thank you! That helps me a lot

Comment: I hate to bother you, but one last question. I am trying to get only specific columns from those DFs. So I what was ' merge_columns = ['rank', 'name'] then called df_list = df_list[merge_columns]' but didnt worked :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106169/discussion-between-maxu-and-mahmut-kilic).